# Growing dynamic array for user input (c-string) without vector

Tags: c++, cin, dynamic-arrays, c-strings

Sorry if you think this problem is useless. I just started my computer science class in college. For one of my assignment, we need to get user input and put it into a c-string using cin.get() function. The professor said We need to do some trick to make the array grow. (Not to make a static or dynamic array with a fix size because it uses too much memory)

Here is one of the code I experimented, but returns error message if my input is too big (obviously, i'm stepping out of the range of the array)

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring> 

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char *hello;
    int max = 2;
    hello = new char[max];
    cin.get(hello, 3000, '\n');
    cout << hello;
    if(max < strlen(hello)){
        max = strlen(hello);
        char *temp = new char[max];
        for(int i = 0; i < strlen(hello); i++){
            temp[i] = hello[i];
        }
        delete []hello;
        hello = temp;
    }
    cout << hello;
    delete []hello;
}
```

Are there any way of doing this without getting errors?

Comment: juste make hello bigger with `hello = new char[3000];`. You wont get any error after this. I dont think there is any other way to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the professor mean you to use `cin.get()` to read single characters.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, Matriac, and no, the professor mean I use cin.get() for input as c string